# How to Set Default Pin State on Orange Pi

Tags: boot, gpio

When booting an Orange Pi the default pin state seems to be HIGH.

Is there a document that I can edit that will change their default state to LOW?

Answer (score 1):

There is a post in the Raspberry PI page which details the process. I know this is a different device, but it should help:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/pin-configuration.md

**EDIT:**

According to this [link](http://piboards.com/2017/01/04/easy-set-up-orange-pi/), there is an utility called "generich3/GPIO" to perform that task.

Comment: I had trouble finding `bootcode.bin`, `dt-blob.bin`, and `config.txt` in the file system.

Comment: I've just edited the answer, have a look to it, please.

Comment: Yes, I left an issue on the `WiringOp` Github page yesterday.

Comment: As fas as I've been reading it involves the kernel and the start-up process, so it seems that or either the manufacture provides a kernel module able to manage this along with a config file or the kernel has to be recompiled.